# Jquery replaceWith() does not update data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I want to replace the delete message with the short URL of each item. The problem is the message keeps displaying the first short URL item that was removed. I want the short URL to be the one I just deleted. Using Ajax and Jquery. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div id="response-message"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
    function removeLink(id){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this link?")){
        $.ajax({
        type:'delete',
        url:'/link/' + id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:{
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            'id':id,
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#response-message').replaceWith('<div class="alert alert-danger mx-auto">Link ' + data.short_url + ' deleted.</div>');
            $('.post'+ data.id).remove();
        }
        });
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public function destroy($id)
{
    $link = Link::findOrFail($id);
    $link->delete();

    return $link;
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `removeLink()`? What is the value of `id`?

Comment: plz add your router

Comment: Can you add your complete html code?

Comment: Also, are you sure the call results in the `success` callback being executed?

Comment: I called it from a button. That's not the problem. The data return from the controller is correct. I've checked on the network and it's the latest one deleted. The problem is just the replaceWith does not change the short url data to the newest one and keeps using the 1st item deleted. @VLAZ

Comment: Are you sure your system allows to use a CRSF token more than once? (Because it does not look like you were updating it between multiple such requests.)

Comment: `replaceWith` can not magically decide what data to use on its own. If your server returned the correct `data.short_url` value, then there is no reason apparent here why this should not work.

Comment: I think so, because it works and the data is been deleted from the db. The return data also displays the data being deleted. @04FS

Answer (score 1):

it`s work for me

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $link = Link::findOrFail($id);
    $link->delete();


    return response()->json($link);
}
```

Comment: doesnt work for me. The short url still dsiplays the first item deleted but on the network data I'm getting the latest item data. I think my Jquery is wrong?

Comment: u need to add ```headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}``` to jquery @HelloWorld1014

Comment: still the same. The weird part is if i use append instead of replaceWith ,, it works but i dont want multiple error messages being displayed. I just want to replace the context.

Comment: why u don`t try with```innerText``` ? @HelloWorld1014

Comment: I'm inserting a div element ,, not plain text